# Getting email from cookie and adding to the uploaded file name

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a gallery page which has the option for users to upload their image, but only registered users can upload. So when the user clicks the Upload button, the upload page checks if the user is logged in or not and if they are not logged in they are directed to the login page like this

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
header("Location: ../login");
}
?>
```

On the login page im setting a cookie like this

```
$_POST['email'] = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
    $_POST['email'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['email']));
    $_POST['password'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['password']));
    $_POST['password'] = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
    $hour = time() + 3600;
    setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['email'], $hour);
    setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['password'], $hour);
```

I am renaming the uploaded file like this

```
//get photo credit and location
$credit = "CR".$_POST['credit'];
$location = "LOC".$_POST['location'];
//generate a random number and then generate a new file name with credit and     location
$new = rand(0000,9999);
$newfilename=$new.$credit.$location;
```

Now I want to add the user email address also to this new file name. I tried

```
$_COOKIE['ID_my_site']
```

but that is not working. Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: FYI, storing email and password in a cookie really doesn't seem like a very good idea ?

Comment: I will remove the storage of password then but I need the email address so that I can add it to the newly upload file name. So that I know which user uploaded the file.

Comment: What is not working? What error are you getting? Additionally, before you use user input (from your POST variables) to rename your file you need to sanitize them as your user input could for instance include characters that are not legal in a file name.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're doing, but generally you store an UUID or some random string in the cookie, and have a lookup table on the server to get the email etc.

Comment: @foxbeefly I am appending the $uploader = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site'] to the $newfilename but that doesn't appear in the new file name. Only the random number, credit and location appears.

Comment: @adeneo I am sorry I am still new to php so didn't get what u said.

Comment: So are your cookies being set? Can you view them in your browser using something like Firebug?
I am pretty sure your setcookie() syntax should be:

setcookie('ID_my_site', $_POST['email'], $hour);
setcookie('Key_my_site', $_POST['password'], $hour);

Comment: Thank u for getting back to me. I can see the saved cookies (they expire in one hour) in firebug on my login page but I can't see them once I am logged in and on the Gallery page. I changed the setcookie functions as u wrote above but still nothing changed.

Comment: Hello foxbeefly thanks but I got it working now :) and answered my question. Please vote it up because its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now. At the time of the login when cookies are being set, I added another line of code:

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
```

This saves the email name of the user who logs in and when he uploads the file, I add the uploader email address to the new filename like this:

```
//get original file name
$file_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];

//get photo credit and location
$credit = "CR".$_POST['credit'];
$location = "LOC".$_POST['location'];

//get the user email from $_SESSION['email']
$uploader = $_SESSION['email'];

//generate a random number and then generate a new file name with credit and location and uploader name
$new = rand(0000,9999);
$newfilename=$new.$uploader.$credit.$location;
```